# selectedindex not working in combobox

Tags: c#

can i know what is the problem with the code which makes it not to work for selectedindex > -1

this code working

```
if (comboBoxSubjectCodeRegister.Text != null)
{
    OleDbCommand oda1 = new OleDbCommand("select subject_abbreviation from subjectinfo where subject_code = '" + comboBoxSubjectCodeRegister.Text + "'", con);
    textBoxSubjectAbbreviationRegister.Text = Convert.ToString(oda1.ExecuteScalar());
}

else
{
    textBox1.Text = "";
}
```

but this not working

```
if (comboBoxSubjectCodeRegister.SelectedIndex > -1)
{
    OleDbCommand oda1 = new OleDbCommand("select subject_abbreviation from subjectinfo where subject_code = '" + comboBoxSubjectCodeRegister.Text + "'", con);
    textBoxSubjectAbbreviationRegister.Text = Convert.ToString(oda1.ExecuteScalar());
}

else
{
    textBox1.Text = "";
}
```

when i use the code which not working in another project, then it works. So strange, but not sure what the problem until now

Answer (score 0):

To provide an "exactly" aswer, we need to know how you are binding the values to the ComboBox.

But, independently of this, it's better to use the `SelectedValue` property instead of `Text`, in your code:

```
if (comboBoxSubjectCodeRegister.SelectedIndex > -1)
{
    OleDbCommand oda1 = new OleDbCommand("select subject_abbreviation from subjectinfo where subject_code = '" + comboBoxSubjectCodeRegister.SelectedValue + "'", con);
    textBoxSubjectAbbreviationRegister.Text = Convert.ToString(oda1.ExecuteScalar());
}
else
{
    textBox1.Text = "";
}
```